# Azure DevOps (on-prem) retrieve team members of a team without AD group members

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have a team in a project where individual team members are added explicitly and an Active Directory group is added. I want to retrieve only the team members who are individually added to the team. I am using the following ADO REST API on Prem ADO 2020.

```
https://{{coreServer}}/{{organization}}/_apis/projects/{{projectId}}/teams/{{team}}/members?$mine=false&$top=1000&$skip&api-version=5.0
```

Using the above the API call, I get the members of the AD group also and I do not want to the members of the AD group.

**Question:** How can I retrieve only individual team members who are explicitly added and avoid listing the team members of AD group.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no URI Parameter to select the members who aren't added by AD group.

You could loop all members and check with `descriptor`.

[image]

If the users are added by AD group, the `descriptor` will start with `aad`.

There are the two members in my test team.

[image]

[image]

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = "PAT"
$OrganizationName = ""
$ProjectName = ""
$teamId = ""

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }

$UriOrga = "https://dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/" 
$uriAccount = $UriOrga + "_apis/projects/$($ProjectName)/teams/$($teamId)/members?api-version=6.0"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader 

$members = $response.value.identity

$Target = @()
ForEach ($member in $members){
    IF($member.descriptor.StartsWith("aad")){
    
    }
    Else {
        $Target += $member
    }
}

$Target
```